# Is there a standard way to automate testing of typescript compile-time constructs like mapped-types?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, mapped-types

Say we're trying to implement the `Pick` [mapped-type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
};
```

We should expect that any type built from this conforms to some typescript compile-time check. Is there a way to test that? Using a testing framework or otherwise?

```
type Foo = { foo: string, bar: string };
type TestType = Pick<Foo, 'foo'>;

// expect this to fail at compile time because of property 'bar'
let foo: TestType = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' };
```

Comment: Looks like this can be accomplished with https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint
Will look more into and answer this with an example